# How I replace 0 with special character Ø when counter start?

Tags: javascript, html

I work with Javascript on html page, my counter work like this :

```
count = count + 1;
```

and the results is :

```
0 
1 
2 
3 
4
.
.
.
10
```

how I create this results :

```
Ø 
1 
2 
3 
4
.
.
.
10
```

document.getElementById("counter").value = count;

Comment: this is an example of separation of concerns. Your counter is the model. It is the responsibility of your view to render it. For example on rendering you could call a function display(c) which returns the string representation of the integer c, with display returning what ever you like such as the number in text or as simply as Nina's solution.

Answer (score 3):

You could take a default value for [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values.

```
document.getElementById("counter").value = count || 'Ø';
```